# Can I call a method right before my app closes?

Tags: android

Here's the situation:

I want to check if the device is rooted or not every time the app comes to foreground (either because they're launching the app through App Drawer or coming back to the app via Recent Apps list). This check is done during onResume(), and it's working well.

The problem is that the intention is to check for root only once when the app comes to foreground, not when user is currently using the app. Since onResume() is called when an Activity comes to foreground, this means the check is done multiple times even when it's not needed, which comes at performance cost.

I thought of using a static variable to lock it, locking just before I perform the check to ensure the check is only called once. This is fine and dandy, but the problem is **when to do the unlock?**

1. onPause() is called before another Activity comes to focus, which
   would negate the lock. I tried to use isFinishing(), but if a user
   presses the back button, the activity is destroyed, which resets the
   root checking lock and renders it less desirable. EDIT: Also, the Activity is not finished if the user presses Home button, which means it's also not reliable enough
2. onStop() and onDestroy() are not guaranteed to be called, and
   they're also called if the user presses back button.

Is there a way to call a function exactly once when the app moves to background, without restricted to the constraints of onPause() above? I searched through the Activity, Application, and BroadcastReceiver documentation but couldn't find any mention about such a thing

Comment: why in onResume()? why not in onStart or onCreate?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want it to check on "focus" resume and not just on "application startup"? The rooted state would barely change without a reboot, so it is nearly impossible that the state changes and your app is still running.

Comment: Like I said, because I need to perform the check every time the app comes to focus. This is to ensure that the user does not open the app, move it to background, root the device (such as with SuperSU app) and then open the app again, which would circumvent a one-time check during first launch. At any rate, the problem is not in when to perform the check, but how to ensure it only runs once

Comment: Perhaps a static counter could help? Say you increment the counter the first time and right after that you have: if (counter==0){// do the root check} else {//don't do it. Move on.}

Comment: @WarrenFaith I have to admit that I do not fully understand how the whole "rooting" business in Android world works. I'm using SuperSU app and it seems to be able to root and unroot without having to reboot the device

Comment: It can give or restrict root access without reboot. Though I don't see a use case where you need to recheck on app focus change. Can you explain why you need it to behave that way?

Comment: @GeorgeD I need to check for rooting every time the app comes to focus, to prevent users from circumventing a one-time-only check upon first launch. However, I understand that this all stems from the belief that rooting does not inherently require rebooting. Is there a knowledge base that can tell me deeper about this rooting business? Especially regarding the need to reboot?

Comment: @WarrenFaith The app deals with sensitive data. I do not want er... "smart" people to gain access to the data in a rooted device. As I understand it, when a device is rooted all hell breaks loose and they can obtain permission to read stuff from my app's data, which under normal device is not possible. Still, like I said I don't really understand about rooting, so perhaps my fears are without grounds?

Comment: @Raestloz Alright. But what do you mean by "when the app comes to focus" don't you mean when the application is opened/has drawn a UI? What do you mean by "focus"?

Comment: @Raestloz so you want to delete data if the user has root access to the device?

Comment: @GeorgeD When I say "when the app comes to focus", I mean when the app comes to foreground, either because the user is launching the app via App Drawer or coming back to the app via Recent Apps list. Now that I think about it, "coming to foreground" seems to be clearer, I'll update the question

Comment: @WarrenFaith Not necessarily, no. For now I just want to block the user from accessing the app when the device is rooted, to prevent them from reading things such as password.

Comment: @Raestloz What if you move your code to operate on the Application's context? See this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html
 and you override onCreate() .

Comment: @GeorgeD I'm under the impression that Application.onCreate() behaves similarly to Activity.onCreate()? In that it's only called if the object has not been created yet, either due to first launch or destroyed to reclaim memory, which would make it unsuitable for my scenario. I have to admit I haven't tried that one. Perhaps I'll try it later

Comment: @Raestloz The Application.onCreate() is called once. When the user launches your app. Please consider taking a look at the documentation as this might be the solution to your problem.

Comment: @Raestloz well there are two glitches in your approach: First you consider that a root user will try to get data within your app and second sensitive data like passwords should be stored encrypted. So even when he as root and he access your data (without starting your app) all data he gets would just be encrypted. Background to foreground does not mean that Application.onCreate() is called again. This only happens if Android killed your app while being in background. My advice: secure your sensitive data by encryption, not by checking root access and "locking the application"

Comment: @WarrenFaith yes the data are encrypted. This is additional security measure, mostly to prevent users from tampering with the app itself

Comment: Then your root check is not really useful mainly because if someone with root wants your data, he goes straight to your APK file, the database and the installation directory. Imho you can skip the root check.

Comment: @WarrenFaith interesting. Just to be sure, if someone roots the device, are they able to, say, listen to my app's connection to a server and intercept the data? By the way, I just found out about onUserLeaveHint(), which seems to be a pretty good way. But I still need to check on this whole root check thing

Comment: @Raestloz I don't even need root to do that. I just need to change the wifi settings to connect to a proxy I control and I can see everything that goes over the "line"...

Comment: @WarrenFaith what about data that I write to my app's personal storage? As I understand it apps can have a storage area only accessible to that particular app, can users access that directory without root?

Comment: A root user is god on his device. You can't hide a file so that he can't see. The only way is a strong encryption of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to use a combination of onUserLeaveHint(), custom startActivity() and onBackPressed() to do it, with some private static and non-static variables

1. I used onUserLeaveHint() to detect when user is going back to Home
   or to Recent apps list.
2. onBackPressed() is used to tell the app that it is used for
   navigation, while another onBackPressed() override is written at the
   app entry point to detect when user is using back button to go back
   to Home (can't believe onUserLeaveHint() doesn't account for that)
3. the custom startActivity() makes sure that onUserLeaveHint() is not
   called when another activity is started. While onUserLeaveHint() has issues with forced interruptions (such as user receiving a call), it is deemed acceptable for now.

I did some research and found [this blog](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html) but it makes use of onStop(), which is not guaranteed to run

Thanks for all the responses. I understand the concern about my security approach, but the question is about detecting when the user is leaving the app